# Tern Autocomplete with Express

Tags: express, configuration, vim-plugin, tern

I'm using the tern_for_vim plugin for developing node applications. Currently various functions aren't displaying and I'm unsure why. For example: none of the html verb functions appear in the autocompletion list `app.get` (after assigning `var app = express()`) however `app.listen` does and I'm unsure why. I have searched around but can't find anywhere documenting usage of tern with express. Does anyone have a solution?

I have the following configuration file:

**.tern-project**:

```
{
  "libs": [
    "browser",
    "jquery",
    "express"
  ],
  "plugins": {
    "node" : {}
  }
}
```

Comment: How is your Tern project config setup? I've never used it with Tern with Express, but you likely need to [configure](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#configuration) it

Answer (score 4):

libs declaration is used for tern [JSON type definitions](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#typedef). Today it doesn't exists **express** tern JSON type definitions, that's why you cannot use it inside your .tern-project

I have created and initialized [tern-express](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern-express) project to support express with tern. Any contribution are welcome!